# Chat Protocols and Client to client connection?

Tags: android, ios, video-streaming, p2p

I'm looking for a protocol/API to implement a video chat application. In this app, the clients connect to a server and when two clients start chat, they don't send/receive data to/from server! Actually I want the clients connect to each other straightly. I want this on iPhone and Android.
I've searched, and found XMPP protocol, but I'm not sure it let p2p connection. 
Anyway, is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can work for the XMPP Protocol which is specially made for chatting purpose.
That helped me a lot in my work. They might have an android version out now.

Answer (score 0):

you can use WIFI or BlueTooth to do P2P apps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I know by socket connection, the p2p chat in local network is available. but the users are not in local area and also they don't have valid IP.

Comment: Well in that case what will be the career to transfer the data? If you can answer then we can think of some solutions....